# How to change the ssh key while doing a "git pull" on a server with multiple users?

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, ssh, config

I am using an ec2 server in which there are two users. Let's call them user1 and user2 with their separate user1key and user2key in the ~/.ssh folder.

My git config file in the ~/.ssh folder looks like this

```
Host user1
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1key
Host user2
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2key
```

I want to use user1 to pull and commit changes to the origin. However, when I run `git pull`, it asks for the passphrase of user2key which I don't have.

I tried using `git config user.name "user1"` inside the repository and then did a `git pull` but it again asked for a passphrase for user2key.

I even tried removing the information for user2 from the config file and run `git pull` again but it still asked for the passphrase for user2key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.name` has nothing to do with authentication to the remote server.

If you are using a ~/.ssh/config with a Host entry named user1, then your remote URL must become:

```
git@user1:user1/repo-name
```

And you can test the connection to `github.com` with `ssh -Tv user1`.

Again, the name of the Host entry is what you need to use for your URL.
It becomes a shortcut for

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/user1key -Tv git@github.com
```

Note: add `User git` in each `Host` subsection, that way you do not even have to specify `git@`.

```
Host user1
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1key
Host user2
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2key
```